# How to properly define *.d.ts (typings) files for plain JavaScript react components

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, typescript-typings

I am working with Typescript and React. While many react components already come with predefined typings, some of them don't. Defining the `*.d.ts` file and throwing it into the `typings` directory is not a big issue. However, in JavaScript, there are **many** ways to export something in a module, and it's by no means uniform. The result is that the Typescript compiler is happy with my typings, but when I use a typescript `import` statement for the typing, then I get `undefined` at runtime.

Could somebody clarify how to write proper `*.d.ts` files for react components? In particular, how do you declare the `export` statements in the `*.d.ts` file if the original untyped JavaScript file...

- ... uses `export class XYZ`?
- ... uses `export default class XYZ`?
- ... uses `export namespace XYZ`?
- ... uses `export default namespace XYZ`?
- ... uses `module.exports`?

There are a **lot** of possibilities here, and some kind of "cooking recipe" would be nice, i.e. "First, always try method X, if X gives you `undefined` at runtime, try Y...".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Typescript does not know about modules that have been imported via JS. As a result you need to declare the module, and then its exported members.

You can declare the members in your globals definition file more or less the way they've been created in their source file. Since we're talking modules only here, we'll skip the ambient contexts and focus on modules.

### Module with Named Components

Given file named `view/alpha.js` with contents:

```
export class Alpha {
    howdy() {}
}
```

OR

```
class Alpha {
    howdy() {}
}

module.exports = {
    Alpha: Alpha;
}
```

Declare module in definition file:

```
declare module 'view/alpha' {
    class Alpha {
        howdy() : void;
    }
}
```

### Module with Default Export

Given file named `view/beta.js` with contents:

```
export default class Beta {
    howdy() {}
}
```

Declare module in definition file:

```
declare module 'view/beta' {
    export = class Beta {
        howdy();
    }
}
```

### Module with Default and Other Exports

Given file named `view/epsilon` with contents:

```
export default class Epsilon {
    howdy() {}
}

export class Zeta {
    howdy() {}
}
```

Declare module:

```
declare module 'view/epsilon' {
    export default class Epsilon {
        howdy() : void;
    }

    class Zeta {
        howdy() : void;
    }
}
```

---

You referred to:

- `export default namespace XYZ`
- `export namespace XYZ`

This is not valid [ES6](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/export). If you are referring to something like `export Delta` where `Delta` contains named classes, then you'd declare it as:

```
declare module 'view/gamma' {
    namespace Delta {
        class Omega {
            howdy() : void;
        }
    }
}
```

Otherwise, can you link an example? I tried googling `export default namespace` but didn't get any non-Typescript examples.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the summary, that's really helpful! My bad on the namespaces, they are indeed only existing in TypeScript itself - I still keep mixing this up. Also, I learned that TypeScript and Babel actually have configuration that deals with the resolution of imports. Perhaps mine were not set up properly and some imports were not working as intended because of that.